# How to remove title bar using surface view for adding camera overlay in android

Tags: android, surfaceview, camera-overlay

I followed [this](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-tutorial-cameraview-with-layer/) link to create camera overlay with an image. But my problem is I can't remove the title bar using the following codes in **onCreate()** method:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

It causes probably for the below's code in onCreate method:

```
getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
```

Now, what can I do and why this is happening? Can anybody explain??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this under the activity tag in manifest file.

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: Thanks @ravi , could you please explain  what "getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);" --mean??

Answer (score 1):

Use following property in your manifest file for the camera activity

```
<activity android:name="youractivityname"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but it requires minimum Sdk Version 14!! which will limit device compatibility of my app.....